# Does prometheus ensure persistency of time series data of infrastructure?

Tags: algorithm, prometheus, monitoring, in-memory-database

Prometheus use [TSDB](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/main/tsdb) database, which is in-memory database(written in GoLang), which is temporary storage, to store time series metrics of infrastructure.

---

Prometheus is supposed to provide time series metrics, which needs permanent storage, to store the information. For example: CPU metrics of a Host for last month.

1. How prometheus handles persistency(permanent storage) of time series data? Because TSDB is in-memory database..
2. How [cortex storage](https://github.com/cortexproject/cortex) different from TSDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Prometheus TSDB is part in-memory, part on-disk. Recent data is kept [in-memory](https://ganeshvernekar.com/blog/prometheus-tsdb-the-head-block/) and backed up on-disk in [WAL](https://ganeshvernekar.com/blog/prometheus-tsdb-wal-and-checkpoint/) (write ahead log) segments, as it's the most frequently accessed. If the instance is shut down the in-memory data can be restored from the WAL. After a few hours the in-memory data is formally saved to the disk in the format of [Blocks](https://ganeshvernekar.com/blog/prometheus-tsdb-persistent-block-and-its-index/). Therefore, all data is persisted until its retention period expires.

Some more good resources can be found in the TSDB READme: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/tsdb/README.md.

Comment: When you say: "*After a few hours the in-memory data is formally saved to the disk in the format of Blocks.*" That means, if this formal save(atomic operation) fails due to crash then there are WAL segments that can be replayed, on restart. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. The WAL is only truncated once the in-memory data has been successfully persisted to the disk.

Comment: When you say, "*persisted to the disk*": do you mean, every prometheus server instance must have one local disk and may or may not have additional remote storage(like Cortex)? or Can we avoid local disk to just maintain remote storage(Cortex), considering the requirement of more storage space?

Comment: "Vanilla" Prometheus must have a local storage disk, and data can be additionally sent to remote write targets, such as Cortex. If you want to forgo that, check out https://github.com/grafana/agent, which doesn't persist any data locally (besides the WAL).

Comment: In case of https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus .... Is local disk a must? Sorry, what is vanilla?

Comment: By “vanilla”, I mean regular Prometheus (https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus), where I local disk is a must.

Comment: What is the database schema of data stored in WAL(Local disk)? Any reference to documentation would be helpful

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/tsdb/docs/format/wal.md